# Modal Element Refreshing Page: NEEDS TO STOP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services

I currently have a webpage that makes a call to a modal element where a user can upload a file.  Once the user clicks upload, the file is uploaded to Amazon Web Services (S3) and the page gets refreshed.  This would be fine except that I am also trying to send metadata about that particular upload event back to a personal server that way there is a record of the event occurring and with the refresh, it can't complete sending the data back to my server.

Here is the code I'm using in my html to declare the button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="closeModal(true)">Upload</button>
```

And here is my JS:

```
$scope.showModal = function(item){
item.$promise.then(item.show);
item.$options.show = true;
};
$scope.showModal = function(item){
item.$promise.then(item.show);
item.$options.show = true;
};

$scope.closeModal = function(result){
if(result){
  console.log("Sending File..."); 
  $scope.modalBox.$promise.then($scope.modalBox.hide);
} else{
  console.log("Closing...");
  $scope.modalBox.$promise.then($scope.modalBox.hide);
}
};

$scope.newDoc = function(){
$scope.uploadModal = {};
$scope.createdString = $scope.uniqueString();
$scope.showUpload();
};

//Show Modal
$scope.showUpload = function(){
$scope.modalBox = $modal({
  title: ' ',
  placement: 'center',
  template: 'documents/docModal.html',
  scope: $scope,
  show: false,
});
$scope.showModal($scope.modalBox);
};
```

A lot of this code is inherited from another project and I'm still new to this.  I figured that if I can't change the HTML (I tried changing the button type from 'submit' to 'button') I'd change the JS and what I found was that it's probably occurring on this line:
`$scope.modalBox.$promise.then($scope.modalBox.hide);`

I don't know how to manipulate this though to keep it from refreshing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It didn't have anything to do with the Angular, JS, nor HTML elements but rather the Amazon Web Services policy.  There was an option in the policy which redirected the form on success.  I just removed this, rehashed the policy and signature and voila! It works like a charm now.  My form submits the files to S3 and it doesn't refresh the page.